# SortUsingSelector для массива из объектов собственного класса

Tags: foundation, objective-c, xcode

Есть класс Complex с полями (double) real и imaginary. Есть массив NSArray complexArray из 5 экземпляров Complex.

В книге было вот такое задание: применить для вышеописанного массива метод `sortUsingSelector`, но не уточнялось какой. Я решил использовать `compare`.

```
[complexArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Был массив такой:

```
5.0+9.0i
2.0+15.0i
3.0+17.0i
6.0+2.0i
7.0+12.0i
```

А после сортировки стал такой:

```
7.0+12.0i
6.0+2.0i
3.0+17.0i
2.0+15.0i
5.0+9.0i
```

Выходит, он его развернул из начала в конец. По какому критерию он так их отсортировал?

Answer (score 1):

Собственно, критерий находится внутри селектора compare: класса `Complex` , как именно он задан полностью на совести программиста, так что в текущем виде вряд ли кто-то ответит на ваш вопрос.